# grouping controller in subdirectories for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I would like to organize my controllers in subdirectories. Here is an example:

routes.rb:

```
resources :locations do
  resources :users
end
```

I would like to put my controller in the appropriate subdirectory:

```
app/controllers/locations/users_controller.rb
```

and the url would be (standard):

```
/locations/1/users
/locations/1/users/new
/locations/1/users/10/edit
...
```

If i had a namespace in my routes I could change my users_controller.rb to

```
class Locations::UsersController < LocationsController
end
```

but it does not work with nested resources, instead I get the following error:

```
 Routing Error
 uninitialized constant UsersController
```

#### Update

It works if I add:

```
resources :locations do
  resources :users
end
match 'locations/:location_id/users' => "locations/users#index"
```

but I would have to add a route for every action and nested resource...

Comment: Im not sure what do you want to do. isnt 
": resources :locations do
  resources :users
end" make it work?

Comment: nope, it does not find the users_controller.rb in the subdirectory...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use just that one route:

```
match 'locations/:location_id/users' => "locations/users#index"
```

That should come before any other resources/matches that might conflict with that match. By default Rails routes are top-bottom.

```
# should be before locations resource
resources :locations do
  resources :users
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to punt all your nested `users` resource over to `locations/users` you can assign a controller to the resource.

```
resources :locations do
  resources :users, :controller => "locations/users"
end
```

Comment: sweet. thx. found the guide chapter: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

Comment: is there a way to do this without specifying :controller => 'locations' for every nested resource? suppose I have 10 nested resource this kinda becomes cumbersome

Comment: did you finded a way?

Answer (score 12):

One can use modules to have nested routes with nested controllers:

```
resources :locations do
  scope module: :locations do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

$ rake routes

```
...
location_users GET /locations/:location_id/users locations/users#index
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Like Kwon says, it's the order that matters. But you can still use a namespace.

.../config/routes.rb

```
namespace :locations do
    resources :users
end
resources :locations
```

.../app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:

```
class LocationController < ApplicationController
```

.../app/controllers/locations/users_controller.rb:

```
class Locations::UsersController < LocationsController
```