# Creating Rails Controller In Sub-directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, terminal

How do I create a rails Events controller in a different directory other than the default:

```
app/controllers/events_controller.rb
```

I need to create in `app/controllers/api/events_controller.rb`

I created the `api` sub-directory and did `cd` in terminal to api.  When I created the controller it still generated in the default `app/controllers/`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can namespace your controllers (generated like this: `rails g controller API::Events`).

Put your controller in the `api` directory within your `controllers` directory and name the controller's class like this:

```
class API::EventsController < ApplicationController
```

More details discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946410/1026898

---

If that is not what you want to do, rails tends to lean in the direction of not putting that controller in a different directory.

It doesn't hurt anything to do so, it's just a bit odd.  The rails generators, by default, are built to put the controllers in the conventional directory.

If you want to change where they are generated you will have to update the generator.

Answer (score 2):

To do that with rails generators:

`rails g controller API::Events`