# How to call a nested controller function from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, nested-function

NodeController:

```
    def show
        def toggle
            run some stuff here
        end
        other random show stuff
    end
```

I want to call the "toggle" function using a link on my show.html.erb view.
How would I go about creating a link_to for this?

<%= link_to "Toggle", :controller=>"node", :action=>"show:toggle" %>????

Comment: why not just use a `checkbox_tag`?

Comment: I'm using the SNMP gem to query/set values on a Cisco switch.  I want to be able to call a function to send a "set" message to the Cisco to set an interface's Administratively up/down status.

Comment: So the "toggle" function will check the current status of the specified interface, and then send a set command to change the status to the opposite.

Comment: In Ruby, you cannot have a method inside a method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864191/is-it-possible-to-have-methods-inside-methods Perhaps you wish to do nested resources? In that case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273069/rails-custom-nested-controller-actions or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583898/grouping-controller-in-subdirectories-for-nested-resources